# Receiving StringIndexOutOfBoundsException but unable to locate the source

Tags: java, substring

My task:
Use scanner method to extract a string, a float, and an int from a line of data.

The data format is:

```
Random String, 240.5 51603
Another String, 41.6 59087
```

etc.

My source snippet:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class readTest { 

        public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException
          {

            System.out.println ("Enter file name");

            Scanner scanInput = new Scanner(System.in); //Scanner for reading keyboard input for file name
            String fileName = scanInput.nextLine(); //Defines file name as a string from keyboard
            File inputTxt = new File(fileName); //Declares the file based on the entered string
            Scanner in = new Scanner(inputTxt);

            do {

            int a; //variable to count how many characters in name
            String baseStringA = in.nextLine(); //read whole line as string
            a = baseStringA.indexOf(","); //defines a as the posistion of the comma
            String reduceStringA = baseStringA.substring(0, a); //reduces string to everything before comma

            Scanner scanA = new Scanner(baseStringA).useDelimiter("[^.0-9]+"); //removes letters and comma from string
            Float numberA = scanA.nextFloat();
            int integerA = scanA.nextInt();

            System.out.print (reduceStringA + numberA + integerA);

            } while (in.hasNextLine());
}
}
```

So I finally managed to spit out this code after researching a few different topics (I am pretty new to any type of coding) and I was so excited that I managed to get the output I wanted. But after attempting to implement a loop to make the process repeat for all of the available lines, I frequently hit a wall with the error java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException after the program prints the output of the first line.

The full error:

```
String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at readTest.main(readTest.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

I tried to research a little, and I'm convinced it comes from my line

```
String reduceStringA = baseStringA.substring(0, a);
```

This seemed more obvious as I tried to read the actual info given by the error, but when I try to trace where the program is having problems I come up empty.

Is anybody able to spot my rookie mistake? Or am I simply going about this process entirely wrong?

The input txt:

```
Stringy String, 77.2  36229 
More Much String, 89.4 24812
Jolly Good String, 182.3 104570
```

is an example of me getting the error

While the input

```
Random String, 240.5 51603
Another String, 41.6 59087
String String, 182.6 104570
```

works as intended

Which is really strange to me.

Comment: `indexOf(..)` returns `-1` when the character that you've specified doesn't exits in the `String`.

Comment: 'readTest.main(readTest.java:43)', what is this line?

Comment: The exception tells you the line number -- readTest.java:43.  There should be no need to "research" to identify the failing line.

Comment: And read the documentation on `indexOf`.  What does it return if the search argument is not found?

Answer (score 2):

```
        int a; //variable to count how many characters in farm name
        String baseStringA = in.nextLine(); //read whole line as string
        a = baseStringA.indexOf(","); //defines a as the posistion of the comma
        String reduceStringA = baseStringA.substring(0, a);
```

If there is no comma in the `baseStringA` `baseStringA.indexOf()` [will return -1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_indexof.htm). Thus then you will try to get sub string (0,-1) and thus the error.

Finally the error comes from here `baseStringA.substring(0, a);` because one of begin index 0 is larger than the end index a (which is -1) - more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: So there must be something wrong with how it is reading in the data, because every line of input text has a comma following the string. Your explanation helps a lot, because I realize what I need to be looking for.

Comment: I can only guess without seeing the file. Check that you don't have an empty line at the bottom of the file.

Comment: the following input file yields the error `Stringy String, 77.2  36229

More much String, 89.4 24812
Jolly good String, 182.3 104570` After displaying the values from the first line. I'll edit this code into the main post as the formatting for comments is off to me.